# Extending self container functions Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following example:

```
var FunctionName = () => {
  return {
    helloWorld() { console.log("hello world"); }
  }
};

var OtherFunctionName = () => {
  return {
    goodBye() { console.log("Bye Bye"); }
  }
};
```

Assuming I haven't done something syntactically wrong in the above, how would I extend `FunctionName` in `OtherFunctionName` so that `OtherFunctionName` has access to `helloWorld` ??

Because the code base may contain an ES6 class, is it possible to use the same method to extend said class into a self contained function to get access to the classes methods?

So:

```
var FunctionName = () => {
  return {
    helloWorld() { console.log("hello world"); }
  }
};

class OtherClass {
  goodBye() { console.log("Bye Bye"); }
};
```

In this case `FunctionName` would extend `OtherClass` to get access to `goodBye`. **Is that possible**

**What are the methods to extend a self contained function on a self contained function.**

and

**What are the methods to extend a class on a self contained function**

*Is this where Object.assign or lodashes `._extend` would come in handy?*

Comment: What do you mean by a "self-container" (or "self-contained") function? Are you looking for something more complicated than `Object.assign(OtherFunctionName(), FunctionName())`? or for the second example `Object.assign(new OtherClass(), FunctionName())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, if you want to use the prototypes, use `Object.create`.
It allows you to create a object with a certain prototype.
Because you don't want to change everything to 'Property descriptors', you could combine it with `Object.assign`:

```
var FunctionName = () => {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(OtherClass.prototype), {
    helloWorld() { console.log("hello world"); }
  })
};
```

If you'd want to support factory functions and classes, this would do:

```
var FunctionName = () => {
  return Object.assign(
    OtherClass.prototype ? Object.create(OtherClass.prototype) : OtherClass(), {
    helloWorld() { console.log("hello world"); }
  })
};
```

Comment: Would the same concept work for extending the OtherFunctionName to get access to its methods?

Comment: Nope, then you'd have to `Object.create` with `OtherFunctionName()` as argument, because you can only get the functions in that object by actually running it. You could check for the existance of `.prototype` to determine whether to use one or another method

Comment: Can you update your example to show how this might works? @MichielDral

Answer (score 1):

You can simply instantiate it:

```
function FunctionName() {
  return {
    helloWorld() { console.log("hello world"); }
  }
}

function OtherFunctionName() {
  var x = FunctionName();
  // you now have access to x.helloWorld in here
  return {
    goodBye() {
      x.helloWorld();
      console.log("Bye Bye");
    }
  }
}
```

This should work the same when `FunctionName` is a constructor not a factory function (just use `new` to instantiate).